# Add active css class on selected tab in react js

Tags: reactjs

I need to add active class css  on click tab, here is the code:

```
<ul>
 <li className="step"><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/personal-information`} >You <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></Link></li>
 <li className="step"><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/content`}>Content <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></Link></li>
 <li className="step"><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/profile-information`}>Profile <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></Link></li>
 <li className="step"><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/rewards`}>Rewards <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></Link></li>
 <li className="step"><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/goals`}>Goals <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></Link></li>
 <li className="step"><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/thanks`}>Thanks <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></Link></li>
 <li className="step"><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/payment`}>Payment <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></Link></li>
 <li className="step"><Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/launch`}>Launch! </Link></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use NavLink, which is
```

> "A special version of the  that will add styling attributes to
>        the rendered element when it matches the current URL."

```
It has a property called activeClassName which handles the active link.

example :

<NavLink
  to="/faq"
  activeClassName="selected"
>FAQs</NavLink>
```

more info can be found in https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md